# Ubuntu 14.04 DIsplay Problem

Tags: nvidia, login, multiple-monitors, display

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on a Thinkpad T530 machine with nvidia NVS 5400M graphics. When I boot to ubuntu, I always stuck at the dark purple screen with 'ubuntu' at the center and five red dots under it.

I can even hear the login sound, but the login interface never shows up. The machine does not freeze as I can login through tty1.

The strange thing is if I use a secondary monitor, the login screen would show up on the second monitor and the secondary monitor would work just fine. And if I go to display settings and turn my built-in monitor off and then on, GUI would show up on my built-in monitor. The same problem will occur after reboot.

Comment: How did you install the driver exactly?

Comment: I installed the driver through 'System Settings' --> 'Software & Updates' --> 'Additional Drivers'

Comment: then it's the same as me. Consider upvoting: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1330213 which is probably the same.